# Are recommendation letter writers asked to rank their students?

Tags: postdocs, recommendation-letter

Suppose a PhD advisor has multiple students who are applying for postdocs to the same universities.

1. Do the universities ask the advisor to rank these students when submitting their recommendation letters?
2. Do universities generally choose to not accept multiple students of the same advisor?

Comment: Not sure "the university" would even notice. Are they applying to the same department, or postdoc advisor?

Comment: Which part of the world are we talking about? I am a bit confused because post-docs are not usually selected at the university/departmental level, at least in the parts of the world I'm familiar with.

Comment: This does happen for PhD admissions (referees have to answer questions like "is this applicant in the top 1%/5%/10%/25% of students you've taught?" etc) but I would be very surprised if it was done for postdocs. You're being hired by an individual to do a job, not being admitted to a university for a course of study. Many factors beyond a simplistic ranking are more important in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I would find it improper to ask for ranking. There are too many factors and an individual professor will only know some of them. Moreover a person has to be a good fit for a particular position and the letter writer can't really make that judgement. I would ignore such a request if it happened and speak only of the qualities of the individuals for whom I'm writing. I can't, however, say that it has never happened.

And, I doubt that the second factor is more than a very minor consideration. While a university might prefer to take students or postdocs from a variety of other places, refusing a great candidate on such grounds would be sub-optimal all around. But, again, it could happen, though I hope rarely.